# how to get sub tag info from HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code:

```
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id = 1><a href="http://google.com" >Link</a></li>
                <li id = 2><a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" >Link</a></li>
            </ul>

<script>
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById(i);
    var liLink = document.getElementById(i).childNodes[0].baseURI;
    console.log(liLink );
  }
  </script>
```

And I see in console

```
   2 "http://google.com".
```

Expected is:

```
 "http://google.com"
 "http://http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

However when I log element, I can see that childNodes[0].baseURI are different.
Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Comment: [That's how `baseURI` works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.baseURI): *"The base URL of an element in HTML normally equals the base URL of the document the node is in."* and *"The base URL of a document defaults to the document's address (as displayed by the browser and available in `window.location`)"*. I assume you want to access the `href` property instead.

Comment: can you try console.log(document.getElementById(i).childNodes[0].baseURI); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the href attribute, rather than the baseURI.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="1"><a href="http://google.com" >Link</a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" >Link</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById(i);
    var liLink = document.getElementById(i).childNodes[0].getAttribute('href');
    console.log(liLink );
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById(i);
    var liLink = document.getElementById(i).childNodes[0];    
    console.log(liLink.href);
  }
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/A6tJ6/)